# Security about a simple REST web service

Tags: web-services, api, rest, security

Here is my little API with two URL :

- `/api/location/list -> GET`
- `/api/location/detail -> GET`

I'm looking for a process to secure this service with authentication. For now, it can be accessed by only one user (me).

I think oAuth is too complex in my case and I found this resource for designing [a simple API](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/).
I understand the principle of private/public key and HMAC but I have a big concern about this :

Say my webservice is consumed by an ajax request with GET verb. I have something like `/api/location/list?apikkey=userid&hash=abcde`.
A end user can easily sniffed the network during the request (via a simple chrome console), capture full url and access directly to the service multiple times (I think it's a case of replay attacks).

Differents resources talk about timestamp or nonce to make a request unique but I'm a bit lost with implementation.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what technology do you use?

Comment: PHP and Symfony 2 framework

Answer (score 1):

You can try JWToken auth specs, simpler than Oauth, but avoid authorization data as url parameter if possible and use Header's request instead.
If needed consider also ssl encryption at tcp level.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try to use a token-based approach for security, as described in this blog post:

- Implementing authentication with tokens for RESTful applications - https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/

The idea is to authenticate to an authentication resource (that can be part of your application) to get temporary token that can be refreshed with a refresh token when expired.

With the use of HTTPS, it seems to be appropriate.

I think that it depends on the security level you expect. Signature-based authentication (the AWS approach) is great but is a bit complex to implement by hand.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks it's helpful. Actually, I'm calling Google place api with curl. I don't think I need authentication because I can secure via ip on Google side.